# Rotated 2d rectangle intersection detection

Tags: c++, c, objective-c, graphics, geometry

I have 2 rectangles they are placed arbitrarily and I have rects all four corner point like

```
struct Rect
{
 NSPoint topLeft; 
 NSPoint topRight; 
 NSPoint bottomLeft; 
 NSPoint bottomRight; 
}
```

I want to check whether 2 rectangles intersects. I am looking a method similar to `NSIntersectsRect` . But `NSIntersectsRect`won't respect the rotation of rectangle. The points in structure  are the points obtained after rotation.

Sample code in Objecitve-C ,C++ or C will be a great help.

Comment: if the rectangles are rotated, it is extremely difficult.  the full answer is explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8011267/area-of-rectangle-rectangle-intersection

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One simple way is to check whether every vertex of one rectangle is on the same and exterior side of an edge of the one, and vice-versa. For faster and more general methods, see 
http://gpwiki.org/index.php/Polygon_Collision and  http://cgm.cs.mcgill.ca/~godfried/teaching/cg-projects/97/Plante/CompGeomProject-EPlante/algorithm.html

Answer (score 2):

See e.g.g [2D Rotated Rectangle Collision](http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_/technical/game-programming/2d-rotated-rectangle-collision-r2604)  on gamedev.net