# Spritekit SkNodes intersection's Rect / Polygon

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, sprite, sknode

I want to determinate the intersection's Rect / Polygon of 2 overlapping `SkNodes` in `Sprite-kit`.

The method :

```
SKNode.intersectsNode(<#T##SKNode#>)
```

returns only **true** or **false** if there is an intersection, but i want to know also the intersection's area.

Can somebody help me? (I want to determinate the green triangle)

[image]

Comment: This [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10962379/how-to-check-intersection-between-2-rotated-rectangles) could help you.

Comment: @appzYourLife it is like `intersectsNode()`, it only return **true** or **false**

Comment: Tell me what you REALLY need to do, maybe there is a better solution

Comment: @appzYourLife i just wanna that my character moves along slopes (2d platformer with custom physics)

Comment: Ok but why do you need the intersection area?

Comment: @appzYourLife for penetration resolution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Googling "area of intersection of two rectangles" shows this has been addressed multiple times on SO, [like here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11670028/area-of-intersection-of-two-rotated-rectangles), [and here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8011267/area-of-rectangle-rectangle-intersection).

As far as Sprite Kit specific: you are going to have to implement some logic (to test for intersection, containment, etc...) and math (to calculate the area of the intersection,) AFAIK there is nothing built into SK to do it for you.