# Intersection of RotatedRect with Rect or RotatedRect OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv

I know it's possible to intersect two Rects in OpenCV in order to get the area of intersection. Is there a way to intersect a RotatedRect with another Rect or RotatedRect in c++?

Comment: no since intersection of rotatedRects dont result in another rotatedRect. But you can draw the rects in single images and count the pixepixel that are set in both images.

Comment: Similar topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8011267/area-of-rectangle-rectangle-intersection

Answer (score 5):

You can use the *[rotatedRectangleIntersection](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga8740e7645628c59d238b0b22c2abe2d4)* function:

```
cv::rotatedRectangleIntersection    (   const RotatedRect &     rect1,
const RotatedRect &     rect2,
OutputArray     intersectingRegion 
)
```